# Trying to use python to convert an windows event log evtx file to json and then to a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

The end goal is to get a windows evtx file to json and then to pandas df.  I've tried several tools that either dropped fields or gave random errors.

Trying this at the moment and feel like it's close.
Using evtx module to trying and append each record to a list as it's printed out...

```
# from evtx import PyEvtxParser
list = []
def main():
    parser = PyEvtxParser(evtx_file)
    for record in parser.records_json():
        list.append(record['data'])
main()
```

and that got me what I thought was a json array.

```
['{\n'
 '  "Event": {\n'
 '    "#attributes": {\n'
 '      "xmlns": "http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event"\n'
 '    },\n'
 '    "EventData": {\n'
 '      "Current Engine Version": "1.1.23050.3",\n'
 '      "Current security intelligence Version": "1.391.123.0",\n'
 '      "Domain": "",\n'
 '      "Dynamic security intelligence Compilation Timestamp": "6/1/2023 '
 '3:23:42 PM",\n'
```

but doing this -

```
df = pd.DataFrame(list)
```

Gives me one column and each record as one long row

then I tried doing this -

```
array = json.dumps(list)
```

and this

```
df = pd.read_json(array, lines=True)
```

Gets me a future warning  FutureWarning: Passing literal json to 'read_json'

and puts everything in one row multiple columns.

Hah, so I have one with all the events in one column, one row and one with all the events in one row and multiple columns.

I'm sure it's something simple but I've been looking at this for two days now, and I'd appreciate any suggestions.

Thanks!!

Comment: First: Don't name your variable `list`. It is a keyword. Don't overwrite it.

Now, what do you think is your "json array"? I just see the first element - and perhaps just half of it. To me it seems it is a _list of JSON-like strings_. Assuming this, each single element should be fine for pandas, like `pd.read_json(my_list[0])`.
Assuming each entry of the list is one record you could also build a complete string first: `'[' + ','.join(my_list) + ']'` and then pass the result to pandas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make the data less complex. Try this:

```py
import json
from pathlib import Path

import pandas as pd
from evtx import PyEvtxParser


def main(evtx_file: Path) -> list:
    parser = PyEvtxParser(str(evtx_file))
    return [json.loads(r["data"])["Event"] for r in parser.records_json()]


if __name__ == "__main__":
    events = main(Path("C:/temp", "Application.evtx"))
    print(len(events))
    dataset = pd.DataFrame.from_records(events)
    print(dataset)
    print(dataset.info())
```

The `records_json` method of `PyEvtxParser` does a partial job - The value of the `data` key is a JSON string. You need to load this and then extract the actual event payload (from the content of the `Event` key - Which is the single column being found by `Pandas`). Once this is done, the dataframe becomes slightly more useful, but it will still contain dictionaries as the internal data structures, because the event log data is actually a fairly complex object. You may want to think about how to pre-process and flatten the data, to make it more useful for what you want to extract from it

Comment: thank you!!!! Just enough to keep going.... stupid question what does the -> in the function mean?  I've seen that in some scripts and was never quite sure what it was.

Comment: It indicates the type that the function returns, which in this case is a list.