# How read a .evtx file and convert to string?

Tags: python, json, xml, windows, binary

I am developing a program that must obtain information from the .evtx file (example in the code), therefore, I want to know if there is a pure way to create my own small library to guide it in a simple way.

I hope to open the file and read the data as string, after that I am seeing how to convert it to XML, Json and other format. but the first problem I have is reading data, since they throw error like (code), I mean it is a new problem for me.

I have this code and it's work:

```py
from win32evtlog import EvtRender, EvtQuery, EvtNext
from win32evtlog import EvtQueryFilePath, EvtQueryReverseDirection, EvtRenderEventXml

from xml.etree.ElementTree import Element
from xml.etree.ElementTree import fromstring

from .database import DatabaseConnection
from .typed import WindowsEventDict


class EventLogParser:
    def __init__(self, exported_log_file: str):
        self.exported_log_file = exported_log_file
        self.database: DatabaseConnection = DatabaseConnection()

    def __get_all_events(self):
        windows_events = []
        query_handle = EvtQuery(
            self.exported_log_file,
            EvtQueryFilePath | EvtQueryReverseDirection,
        )

        while True:
            raw_event_collection = EvtNext(query_handle, 1)

            if len(raw_event_collection) == 0:
                break

            for raw_event in raw_event_collection:
                item = self.__create_data(raw_event)
                windows_events.append(item)

        return windows_events

    def __xml(self, raw_event):
        return EvtRender(raw_event, EvtRenderEventXml)

    def __access_three(self, raw_event):
        xml_content = self.__xml(raw_event)
        root: Element = fromstring(xml_content)
        return (root, "{" + root.tag.split("}")[0].strip("{") + "}")

    def __get_data_system(self, raw_event):
        root, ns = self.__access_three(raw_event)
        system = root.find(f"{ns}System")
        id_event = system.find(f"{ns}EventID").text
        level_event = system.find(f"{ns}Level").text
        time_created = system.find(f"{ns}TimeCreated").get("SystemTime")
        computer = system.find(f"{ns}Computer").text

        return (id_event, level_event, time_created, computer)

    def __get_data_event(self, raw_event):
        root, ns = self.__access_three(raw_event)
        data_event = root.find(f"{ns}EventData")

        data: str = """"""

        for _data in data_event.findall(f"{ns}Data"):            
            if _data is None:
                pass
                        
            data += f"{_data.attrib['Name']}:{_data.text}; "

        if data is None:
            return "Event data not provided"
        
        return data

    def __create_data(self, raw_event):
        data_system = self.__get_data_system(raw_event)
        data_event = self.__get_data_event(raw_event)

        id_event: int = int(data_system[0])
        level_event: int = int(data_system[1])
        computer_name: str = str(data_system[3])
        created_at: str = str(data_system[2])

        return WindowsEventDict(
            {
                "id_event": id_event,
                "level_event": level_event,
                "computer_name": computer_name,
                "data_event": data_event,
                "created_at": created_at,
            }
        )

    async def insert_data(self):
        events = self.__get_all_events()
        await self.database.execute_query(events)
```

but how I type, I want to buid from zero and i'll be more flexible:

```py
with open('./archivo-prueba.evtx', 'rb') as f:
    codificaciones = ['utf-8', 'latin-1', 'ascii']
    while (byte := f.read()):
        print([byte.decode(item) for item in codificaciones])
```

finally to throw a error like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\eramirez\Desktop\evtx visualizer\a.py", line 4, in <module>
    print([byte.decode(item) for item in codificaciones])
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x83 in position 24: invalid start byte
```

Comment: If the file is not encoded as UTF-8, it can't be decoded this way.

Comment: @MichaelButscher it can be decoded? or I should be by other way?

Comment: (1) Try to decode the whole file at once, not byte by byte because the latter will probably fail even if it is UTF-8-encoded. (2) Catch the exception in a try-except-block to be able to continue with the next encoding. (3) "latin-1" is a superset of "ascii" so either try "ascii" before "latin-1" or (recommended) don't use it at all.

Comment: I try follow your instructions to finally its working but I get this:                         ```cmd     b'ElfFile\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x83\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x80\x00\                                                                                                                                       ```

Comment: Have you gave a try the [pypi](https://pypi.org/project/evtx2pandas/)?

Comment: yeah I try that but return this `"." is not recognized as an internal or external command,
program or executable batch file.` when I try this: `from evtx2pandas.json_to_csv import EvtxParser

try:
    reader = EvtxParser()

    # To write evtx as json
    reader.evtx_to_json(evtx_path=r'C:\Users\eramirez\Desktop\evtx visualizer\archivo_prueba.evtx', output_path=r'C:\Users\eramirez\Desktop\evtx visualizer\src')

    print(reader.evtx_to_json('archivo_prueba.evtx'))

except Exception as ex:
    print(ex)`

Comment: compare  also [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77283475).